# How to obtain all distinct items but limit each distinct to max n and ordered by date?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I have `uuid` as PK, `command_name` string, `count_successful` integer and `command_start` date.

I can grab all records by:

```
select 
    uuid, 
    command_name, 
    count_successful, 
    command_start 
from 
    sync_logs 
order by 
    command_start desc;
```

But above query will give me for example `78` records where `command_name` equals to `foo` and `45` records with `command_name` equals to `bar`.

How can I get max of `10` recent records per `command_name`?

Comment: See the added tag.

Comment: Specify MySQL version, in this case it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently below query solves the issue and gives me recent 10 records for each `command_name` ordered by command name and when it started.

```
select
    s1.* 
from
    sync_logs as s1
left join 
    sync_logs as s2 
on 
    s1.command_name = s2.command_name and 
    s1.command_start <= s2.command_start
group by 
    s1.uuid
having 
    count(*) <= 10
order by 
    command_name asc, 
    command_start desc;
```